# Issue with PDO fetch

Tags: php, pdo

I have this snippet of code that completely screws up when I run it.  It doesn't even throw an exception.  It just causes a server error.

```
    try {
        $stmt = $this->database->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM news_posts");
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $array = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($array);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "error?";
    }
```

Comment: Check your error log. You shouldn't write code until you have methods to debug your code, and part of that is setting up error logging.

Comment: So what is this server error? Whatever caused it should be in your error log. Also, make sure `display_errors` is `On` if you do, actually, want to see errors.

Comment: it is a 500 internal server error.  I turned on error reporting and this is what I'm getting: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object.

Comment: I figured it out.  I didn't need to be returning the execute to $result.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDOStatement::execute()` doesn’t return its results; you call `fetch` on the query.

```
$stmt = $this->database->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM news_posts");
$stmt->execute();
$array = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($array);
```

You could also shorten that to `query()`, since you’re not adding any parameters:

```
$stmt = $this->database->query('SELECT * FROM news_posts');
$array = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if PDO is turned on in php.ini.
You can check it also via phpinfo() script.
Remember about setting appropriate error levels via:

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);